# I want to do String validation

Tags: javascript

We need to consider the below string as use cases , First I want to split 
     by "," then by "@"

After Splitting by @ if all the domain are same(either all gmail or all yahoo) its valid 
   else invalid.

Help me with split part.

```
String input1 = example@gmail.com , example1@gmail.com; 
String input2 = example@yahoo.com , example1@gmail.com;


    String input 1 == valid.
    String input 2 == Invalid.
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)? Please show us how.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: I am able to split first time with , and after splitting with , .. How to split the same string with @

Comment: @MohammedSohail you should look at the variable type of the return from `split()`. The `split` function is called on a string and returns an array of strings. So for your `input1`, split would return `["example@gmail.com "," example1@gmail.com"]`. To do another split, you will need to apply it to each item in the array. I recommend looking at the [Array map() method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the domains, and then add them to a `Set` and see if they were unique by checking the size of the `Set`.

An added extra, is that this will work regardless of the number of emails in the string.

```js
const input1 = 'example@gmail.com , example1@gmail.com';
const input2 = 'example@yahoo.com , example1@gmail.com';

function validInput(input) {
  const domains = input.split(',').map(email => email.trim().split('@')[1])

  return new Set(domains).size === 1;
}

console.log('is input1 valid ?',validInput(input1));
console.log('is input2 valid ?',validInput(input2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example, you can access array from the split with [0] and [1].

```
var input = 'example@gmail.com , example1@ymail.com, example1@yahoo.com';
input.split(',').forEach(email => {
  const domain = email.split('@')[1].trim();
  if (domain === 'gmail.com' || domain === 'yahoo.com') {
    console.log("Email address " + email + " is valid.");
  } else {
    console.log("Email address " + email + " is not valid.");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function

```
isValid = (emails)=>{
    let list = emails.split(','), isValid = true

    list.forEach((email)=>{
        if(!email.includes('@gmail.com')){

          isValid = false
        }
    })

    return isValid
}

isValid(' example@gmail.com , example1@hotmail.com;')
```

Split by ,
Then check each email with includes
You could add a secound parameter to check the email type and make it more universal

```
isValid = (emails, validEmail)=>{
    let list = emails.split(','), isValid = true

    list.forEach((email)=>{
        if(!email.includes(validEmail)){

          isValid = false
        }
    })

    return isValid
}

isValid(' example@gmail.com , example1@hotmail.com', '@gmail.com')
```